# MockMvc append charset to content type header

Tags: spring-boot, mockmvc

After upgrade Spring Boot v 2.3.4 to 2.3.8. Some tests failed. I found that MockMvc auto append charset to content-type header.

```
  var request = post("/proxy/airbank/oauth2/token")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .content("{\"key\":\"value\"}");
```

in controller arrive header in format

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = POST
  Request URI = /proxy/airbank/oauth2/token/revoke
   Parameters = {b1Key=[b1Value], b2Key=[b2Val]}
      Headers = [Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", cipherId:"tCipherIdFromRequest", Content-Length:"25"]
         Body = b1Key=b1Value&b2Key=b2Val
Session Attrs = {}
```

I'm not able persuade MockMvc to disable auto adding this annoying feature...

FYI: I'm validating header for exactly content, manual updating/changing tests will takes plenty of time

Comment: It is strange that there is no suggestion for that, specially MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE is now deprecated !